# CRTP variable inizializatin in derived class

Tags: c++, initialization, default-constructor, crtp

Consider the following code implementing CRTP

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class base {
    int n;
    base() {}
    friend T;
public:
    explicit base(int _n) : n{_n} {}
    void print() const { static_cast<const T&>(*this).whoami(); }
};

class derived : public base<derived> {
public:
    void whoami() const { std::cout << n << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    base<derived> a{6};
    a.print();
}
```

The code prints 6 as expected.

The default constructor `base::base()` would leave the member field `n` uninitialized. However, since it is `private` and `base` is `friend` to `derived`, only `derived` uses `base::base()` (specifically, in its compiler-generated default contructor). But `derived` has not public constructors, so it is never instantiated. So the code seems to be safe from the point of the initialization of  `n`, though there is a part of the code that, effectively, does not perform the correct initialization.

So I wonder: is there a pitfall in a code like above?

****Note****

Please notice that the question it not merely academic. In a real-world case, the members of `base` may not have a sensible default initialization, and are initialized by a constructor of `base` that takes a series of parameters. These parameters can be possibly determined at runtime only, and used in `main()` to instantiate `base<derived>`.

```
class base {
public:
    base(int param1, char *param2);
};
```

If there is no default constructor for `base`, you need a constructor for `derived` that calls the constructor of the base class `base<derived>`. When this has no sensible default parameters, it would be very awkward to call it with
"random" parameters

```
class derived : public base<derived> {
    derived() : base<derived>(42, "unexisting_file") { }
};
```

Comment: Generally you only want to declare an object once you actually have the parameters to create the object.  If you have a control flow like `declare object; if(condition) object = this_way; else object = that_way;` then one way to "bypass" the default construction is to use a `unique_ptr` and then in the sub scopes you would use `make_unique` to assign to that pointer a newly created object with the parameters that are actually valid.

Comment: As an alternative for the solution by @NathanOliver, you could use a factory function taking the result of the condition as an argument, and returns an object. Perhaps like `object_type create(bool condition) { if (condition) return this_way; else return that_way; }` Then you could simply do `auto object = create(condition);`

Comment: *is there a pitfall in a code like above?*  **Yes**, it's undefined behavior.  Because `base<derived>` is not a `derived` in `main` (for the code provided), so casting `*this` to `derived const&` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You never create a `derived` instance. What is its point? (I suspect that you believe this is valid since the compiler doesn't complain about your `static_cast`, but it's not a valid cast in this code. The compiler can only check that it's *potentially* valid, but it's your responsibility to ensure that `*this` really is a `T`.)